# Solving Coulomb Integral in 1D

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, mathematical-physics

I am trying to solve the following Coulomb integral of two gaussians:

$$
\int_{- \infty}^{ \infty}dx1\int_{- \infty}^{ \infty} \frac{e^{-b1 (x1-c1)^2}e^{-b2 (x2-c2)^2}}{\left | x1-x2 \right |}dx2,
$$

where $b1,b2,c1,c2$ are real parameters and $b1$ and $b2$ are positive. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?  I was trying to use the Gaussian product rule, but I could not get an analytic expression in the end.

Comment: Use either the Fourier transform  $1/|\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|=(2\pi)^{-3} \int 4\pi e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot(\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2)}/k^2 d\mathbf{k}$ or the identity $1/|\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2| = \pi^{-1/2} \int e^{-s^2 |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2} ds$. You then need to figure out a change of variables to bring it to the form of an error function. This is a standard problem in quantum chemistry, where a more general integral is usually expressed in terms of the Boys function (try Googling "boys function coulomb integral").

Answer (score 1):

just as partical answer:
Using polar coordinates ($x_1=r cos(\theta), x_2 =r sin(\theta)$, |det(J)|=r) will give you an standard gaussian integral in the radial variable...